# Meaning of "medicines capsules with instructions for giving them"

Tags: meaning-in-context

"A Day’s Wait" by E. Hemingway

Sentence:

> Downstairs, the doctor left three different medicines in different colored capsules with instructions for giving them.

Questions:

1. What is "instructions for giving them"?
2. Why the word "giving" is used here?

Comment: What exactly is confusing you about this sentence? The word giving seems to be pretty obvious, and as for the instructions part, doctors who prescribe a medicine will also provide the frequency, timing, dosage etc. for correct treatment

Comment: @ColonD - Any time a word has well over a [dozen definitions](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/give_1), I try to be careful about saying that its meaning should be "pretty obvious." That said, I do think this definition, found in [Wordnik](http://wordnik.com/words/give), might be helpful: *To administer: give him some cough medicine*.

Answer (score 2):

"Instructions for *giving* them" are intended, for example, for a parent giving medications to a child, for a doctor giving them to school children, for a nurse giving them to an older person in a nursery home or for someone giving them to a dog.

"Instructions for *taking* them" are intended for a reader of the instructions who will be also the one who will take the medications.

Comment: It's worth pointing out the different nuances of the word _give_ that may make a learner more confused. After all, a parent can _give_ a lollipop to a child, a man might _give_ an old lawnmower to his neighbor, a dog owner might _give_ a dog a bone, and a doctor might _give_ some advice to a patient. These instances of _give_ are not quite the same as "giving medicine", which, as you say, is more about how to _take_ the medication (i.e., proper frequency and dosage).

Comment: @J.R. Yes, an example are instructions for a doctor how to give an injection.

Answer (score 1):

In English, we say: to **give medicine(s) to someone based on instructions** that come with the medicine (medication, pills) or are provided by a doctor.

In the field of medicine, the **formal** way to say "**give medicine to someone**" is **"to administer medication to a patient"**.